# how to insert our own character into mysql which is not in other unicodes

Tags: mysql

hey I have a problem  with the MySQL. I am working on a website now and I need to insert some of the characters into MySQL database which are not in Unicode. Is it possible to do this? If it is then how? 
here is the picture of this symbols

[image]

Comment: These characters should be save directly in mysql using Charset `latin1` and Collation `latin1_swedish_ci`. may be problem while inserting with php or some another server side language. you should check with mysql database adding above text directly into table.

Comment: Can you provide us with a link with detailed CS related informations about these characters? There are a LOT of Unicode characters and why do you believe these characters are not included in Unicode?

Comment: I already solved it with different way. Thanks